# Multiple AVPlayer instances working simulator but not on Apple TV

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, tvos, apple-tv

I'm currently trying to play multiple AVPlayers in parallel using AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer on tvOS. In the simulator this is working correctly, on the device only some players play and for the rest the player layer simply stays blank (not even black but simply blank). I've heard rumors that the internal implementation only supports 24 simultaneous instances so I already limited the number to 24. However on the physical device, a number of ~15 players can play in parallel. Surprisingly that number tends to differ, sometimes its just 13, sometimes even 16.

I'm creating the players using the following code (which is executed in a closure, hence the weak self as the input and the strongSelf cast):

```
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        strongSelf.player = AVPlayer(URL: localURL)
        strongSelf.player?.volume = 0.0
        strongSelf.player?.actionAtItemEnd = .Pause
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(strongSelf, selector: "playerPlayedToEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: strongSelf.player?.currentItem)

        strongSelf.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: strongSelf.player)
        strongSelf.playerLayer?.frame = strongSelf.contentView.bounds
        strongSelf.playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        strongSelf.contentView.layer.addSublayer(strongSelf.playerLayer!)

        strongSelf.player?.play()

        strongSelf.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
```

Would any of you have an idea what could cause this problem? I'm also open to any workarounds if any of you could suggest one :)

Comment: This isn't actually much of a surprise. There used to be a rule even on iOS that There Can Be Only One (movie playing - see my book, http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch28.html#SBonlyOne). So the idea that this restriction would be true on the TV is not a big stretch.

Comment: Yeah that might be true for MPMoviePlayerController (which is not available on tvOS). What I forgot to mention (edited my post above): The number of players that can be active simultaneously differs! Its not always 15, sometimes its 13, sometimes even 16.

Comment: It wasn't just true for MPMoviePlayerController. MPMoviePlayerController is just a wrapper around AVPlayerLayer, like all other video display. I am suggesting that you're hitting an inherent limit. And I'm saying that the idea that that limit might be larger than 1 is actually the surprise.